# SQL Server random numbers using CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am generating random numbers using CTE(instead of a loop) using the below query. Weird thing is that the query doesn't generate random numbers after Indexer value 2. You can look at the [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90208/37). Is there any explanation for that behavior of CTE?

```
   ;with LoopCounter
    as(
       select 1 Indexer, RAND() RandNumber
        union  all
        select Indexer + 1, RAND()  RandNumber
        from LoopCounter
        where 
          Indexer <= 1000
      )
    select *
    from LoopCounter  
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: You can add the Indexer as a seed to RAND(): ...`select Indexer + 1, RAND(Indexer + 1)  RandNumber`...

Comment: There are multiple optimizations that will prevent RAND() from being evaluated more than once (or in your case, once for the anchor, and once for the recursive part). Here's an idea to thwart this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72319/4 (this also includes Paul's suggestion, which doesn't rely on any of the schema in the left pane).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   ;with LoopCounter
    as(
        select 1 Indexer,  ABS(Cast(Cast(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as INT) as Float)) / Cast(0x7FFFFFFF as int) RandNumber
        union  all
        select Indexer + 1,  ABS(Cast(Cast(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as INT) as Float)) / Cast(0x7FFFFFFF as int)  RandNumber
        from LoopCounter
        where 
          Indexer <= 1000
      )
    select *
    from LoopCounter  
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```